# Why does cassandra count query using "allow filtering" when being executed without mentioning it in my code?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-java-driver

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1 ,spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1 with java8.

I am doing simple query as below to get the C* table row count.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
long recCount = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(keyspace, columnFamilyName).cassandraCount();
```

> But it is timing out with following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT count(*) FROM "radata"."model_vals" WHERE token("model_id", "type", "value", "code") > ? AND token("model_id", "type", "value", "code") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:350)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
```

> I am using Cassandra 6 node cluster with below settings :

```
 cassandra.output.consistency.level=ANY
cassandra.concurrent.writes=1500
cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes=2056
cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key=partition 
cassandra.output.batch.grouping.buffer.size=3000
cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec=128
cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms=30000
cassandra.read.timeout_ms=600000
```

> 1) Why it is interpreting with appending "ALLOW FILTERING" before
>   executing it actually ?
>
> 2) Even thought I set "cassandra.output.consistency.level=ANY" why it is 
>     executing with "consistency LOCAL_ONE" ?
>
> How to fix these issue ?

Answer (score 2):

1. ALLOW FILTERING is implicitly added to the generated CQL query by Spark-Cassandra connector.
2. Consistency level is set per query, and is set on Spark side. You can use

> spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=ANY

on **Spark** config.

But changing consistency level doesn't help you because your only one Cassandra node doesn't response. I suggest that your table is pretty large and time spending Cassandra to calculate count is more than any of timeout parameters. This parameters can be set per query on the client side. In your case you can take a look at Spark-Cassandra connector configuration: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md

Another way is to calculate count on Spark side and put .count() instead of .cassandraCount() . From my experience I recommend to avoid any aggregations on Cassandra side on production. Especially, when you are using Spark - framework that is designed for such kind of tasks.

Comment: "you mean I need to use spark .read() .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") .option("table", columnFamilyName) .option("keyspace",keyspace ) .load().count() ?? "

Actually, yes.